# I can't buy a streak filter where I live. How do go about making myself one for my DSLR?

Tags: dslr, filters, diy

Generally used to achieve the anamorphic 'streak' effect.

Comment: Hmmm short google later and I found a web site you can order them from, they even do international shipping. http://www.optefex.com/streak-filters

Answer (score 5):

The best ones use thin sheets of glass etched with regular parallel lines. It would be possible to replicate this approach using an old UV filter, a an etching tool and some sort of straight edge, but you can get the same effect by stretching several pieces of fishing line across a frame in front of the lens.

Comment: The fishing line idea is slick, there's lots of thicknesses and some different colours out there for even more variance. If you have a Cokin or Lee filter holder and some 1mm thick card stock, you're really in business. I may have to try this.

Comment: Try coating a cheap (glass!!!) UV filter with permanent marker, then make a scratch pattern in the marker paint with a metal object (softer than the glass, so a quality knife or hardened needle is not recommended...)